# Spring Boot tomcat threadpool configuration

Tags: spring-boot

We are using Spring Boot version - *spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.4.3.RELEASE.*

We are trying to find the max-threads configuration for the embedded tomcat, but in vain.

We could not find any server.xml inside the Spring Boot jar file. Neither could we print the max-threads property - which always returns null.

How can I find out the max-threads configured in the embedded tomcat for Spring Boot 1.4.3? How can I set the max-threads?
Does Spring Boot 1.4.3 use NIO?

Answer (score 6):

The default value for max-threads is 200. From the tomcat [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)

You can set it using the property

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=<your value> # Maximum amount of worker threads.
```

From the spring-boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: What is the max number? It cannot be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

for configuring that you will change application config in (application.yml or prop)
like this

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=12
```

Comment: We tried setting this property and then retrieving it. But always get zero.

Comment: Where did you put it?